# HTML: Spanning a form across multiple td columns

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I'd like to be able to do something like this in HTML. It isn't valid HTML, but the intent is there:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Favorite Color</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
            <td><input name="name" value="John"/></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color" value="Green"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/></td>
        </form>
        <td>
            <form action="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
            <td><input name="name" value="Sally"/></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color" value="Blue"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/></td>
        </form>
        <td>
            <form action="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously, I can't do this because I must not have a form tag immediately inside of of a `<tr>` element. The only alternatives I can see are to use nasty javascript or to change the behavior of my program.

What might be a solution that would allow me to have a form that spans multiple columns like this?

Answer (score 6):

One option is to combine the columns with colspans like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Favorite Color
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
                    <input name="name" value="John"/>
                    <input name="favorite_color" value="Green"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/>
            </form>
            <form action="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
                <input name="name" value="Sally"/>
                    <input name="favorite_color" value="Blue"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/>
            </form>
            <form action="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And style the form element's layout with CSS. Or you can go with a pure DIV based layout.

Answer (score 3):

I'd vote for the nasty Javascript. It would allow to keep the layout as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Old posting I know, but for anyone else looking this up...

It seems to be that all responses to now are so determined to answer your question, that they're forgetting to consider there might be a much simpler way.

There may be that hidden behind your question, there's a reason you can't do this.  But the "correct" HTML-valid way to do what you're trying to do is to place the entire table inside a single form.  Why do you need one form to edit, and another to delete?

```
<form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Person Name</th><th>Fave Color</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" value="John" name="name_1"></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color_1" value="Green"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit_update_1"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit_delete_1"></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" value="James" name="name_2"></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color_2" value="Orange"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit_update_2"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit_delete_2"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

You need a bit of logic in your ASP/PHP/server-code to calculate which button-name was pushed, but you need that anyway using your proposed solution.

Comment: That's not a solution. What if I really wanted a form for each and every user? Perhaps to incorporate a toggle button to set some flag via AJAX. If I did that against a REST service (okay, your post is from 2012 but for anyone reading) then I couldn't rely on the server figuring out which button was pressed and the like.

Comment: @Balázs From what I remember, I wasn't aware of this in 2012, but HTML5 allows you to associate a submit button with a form without the submit button having to be a direct descendant of the form itself. This would resolve the original problem (at the cost of making the code somewhat harder to maintain and intuitively understand). Nevertheless, even given this HTML5 ability, I don't understand your objection. There's no reason that a REST service can't be intelligent enough to disregard the data that isn't relevant to its operation.

Answer (score 2):

Use table-less design with Div's and CSS.

Eg.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper
    {
        width: 600px;
    }
    #header
    {
        width: 600px;
        height:30px;
    }
    #person
    {
       clear:both;
        width:600px;        }
    .name
    {
    clear:both;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .color
    {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .submit
    {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="name">
            <b>Name</b></div>
        <div class="color">
            <b>Favorite Color</b></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Person">
        <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
        <div class="name">
            <input name="name" value="John" /></div>
        <div class="color">
            <input name="favorite_color" value="Green" /></div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Person" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are some things that floats just don't accomplish well. A table will keep it's form factor until the bitter end, where as a float will happy just drop down to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be if your multiple columns were actually created in `DIV`s instead of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there isn't such form.
But, in many browsers, your usage is working like you expected, except for when you dynamicly creat DOM elements with such structure in FireFox.

Maybe you can throw away the <form> tag, use javascript to do the submit;
Or you can use <div> to do the table layout thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could

a) combine entire table row in one form and handle it with one server-side script.

or

b) set form.action with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.rowForm').submit(function() {
        //console.log($(':input',$(this).closest('tr')));
        //Because u cant span a form across a table row, we need to take all the inputs, move it to hidden div and submit
        var rowFormContent = $('.rowFormContent',$(this));
        rowFormContent.html('');    //Clear out anything that may be in here            
        $(':input',$(this).closest('tr')).clone().appendTo(rowFormContent);

        return true;
    });
});
</script>

<tr>
 ...
 <td>
   <form action="/cool" method="post" class="rowForm" id="form_row_1">
   <div class="rowFormContent" style="display: none;"></div>
   <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>
 </td>
</tr>
```

The side effect is you'll get an extra submit input type in your form, but it will be hidden and should not hurt anything. A subtle note here, is the use of ':input'. This is jQuery shorthand for all input types (select,textarea etc). Watch out for [select vals not being copied](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2941). You'll have to do some trickery (hidden field) to submit the current selected val of a clone()d select.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried numerous ways to solve the same issue; multiple forms within a single html table. FF & Chrome will automagically close  if  is placed before or within a  or  because its not semantically correct html. I appreciate  based layout would solve the problem but if you 'need' to stick with the table based layout you'll need to use multiple tables and wrap the  &  immediately before and after the  &  tags. In my case I then made some small inline CSS adjustments to remove a border or two and then the table butts up against each other as if they were rows.

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/chopstik/ve9FP/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, solved it using Javascript/jQuery.
The problem here is that form can't stretch across multiple columns in a table, however if the form has id `<form id="unique_per_page"...></form>` each of the stand-alone form elements like input, select or even textarea can be assigned to that form using form attribute `<input type="text" name="userName" form="specific_form_id">`

The jquery/javascript to assign these things will need to have a random string generator, which I grabbed from the following [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964557/5050988)

So overall the code will look like this:

```
    $("table tr").each(function(i, el){
        if(!$(el).find("form[name='updatePerson']").attr("id"))
        { //if the form does not have id attribute yet, assign a 10-character random string
            var fname = (Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, 10+2);
            $(el).find("form[name='updatePerson']").attr("id",fname); //assign id to a chosen form
            $(el).find("input").attr("form",fname); //assign form attribute to all inputs on this line
            $(el).find("form[name='deletePerson'] > input").removeAttr("form"); //remove form attribute from inputs that are children of the other form
        }
    });
```

The HTML code you included will need to be updated with the proper name attributes for the forms

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Favorite Color</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form action="/updatePerson" name="updatePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
            <td><input name="name" value="John"/></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color" value="Green"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/></td>
        </form>
        <td>
            <form action="deletePerson" name="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form action="/updatePerson" name="updatePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
            <td><input name="name" value="Sally"/></td>
            <td><input name="favorite_color" value="Blue"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/></td>
        </form>
        <td>
            <form action="deletePerson" name="deletePerson" method="post">
                <input name="person_uuid" value="f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

The way I've always done it is:

```
<tr>
    <td><form><input name=1></td>
    <td><input name=2></td>
    <td><input type=submit></form></td>
</tr>
```

Include the **form** inside the first and last **td**, so it's in an actual text area.  It's possible that really old browsers will close the form at the **/td**, but none today.

With your example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <form action="/updatePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
    </td>
    <td>    <input name="name" value="John"/></td>
    <td>    <input name="favorite_color" value="Green"/></td>
    <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Person"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="deletePerson" method="post">
            <input name="person_uuid" value="550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete Person"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is not a valid html.